# AngularJs: Show/Hide table column based on dropdown in first column

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using angularjs

I have a table which column one I am binding it to a an array.

Second column is a dropdown.

I want to have other 5-6 columns (text and dropdown) which I want to show/hide based on the value of second column dropdown.

I tried the below code:

```
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
       <td >{{item.name}}</td>
       <td >  
          <select name="utype" class="form-control input-medium"  ng-model="utype">
                  <option value="">---Please select---</option>
                  <option ng-repeat="type in types" >{{type.text}}</option>
          </select></td>
      <td><span ng-hide="utype =='Type1' || utype!=undefined" >{{item.value}}</span></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-small" ng-click="edit(item)">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

ng-hide="utype =='Type1' || utype!=undefined"
```

But this only works the first time. After hiding it does not work.

Could anyone point what I need to do to make it work:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`utype!=undefined` is always true after you set `ng-model="utype">` the first time.
Take out `utype!=undefined` and try it.

```
<td><span ng-hide="utype =='Type1' >{{item.value}}</span></td>
```

Also, imo, you should use `===` rather than '=='. see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons) for details.
 
e.g.. `ng-hide="utype ==='Type1'`

Comment: This does not work. That column is now hidden and doesnt show even after changing ddl value

Comment: post your new code. And what are the values in your array?

Comment: If the expression in ng-hide is evaluating to true then the <td> will be hidden. 
Check that your expression `ng-hide="utype ==='Type1'` is evaluating to true/false correctly.  To check this, put this line somewhere in your hmtl `ng-hide value is {{utype ==='Type1'`}} `